# Flutter Desktop App - Google SignIn (redirect_uri?) in production site

Tags: flutter, google-oauth, flutter-desktop

Right now, I can be able to sign in with my google account in the flutter desktop app for dev environment. What I am doing:

- creating a web server with HttpServer package inside the flutter project

```dart
HttpServer _redirectServer = await HttpServer.bind("localhost", 8082);
```

- Setting up redirect_uri **http://localhost:8082** in the google oauth2 console (type is the web application)
- Then redirect the users to the google sign in page. After user grants the permission, then i am catching the google response:

```dart
var request = await _redirectServer.first;
```

- The rest is just to get access token vs ...

Everything is working correctly in the localhost, but I just confused about the production site
Now, let's assume that I released my application in the Microsoft store and apple store. Let's also assume that I have backend application running in the domain https://api.myapp.com (or [https://api.myapp.com:{anyPort}](https://api.myapp.com:%7BanyPort%7D)). In that scenario, what should be the redirect_uri?

Answer (score 1):

Updating the redirect URL from `http://localhost:8082`  to your server domain url `https://api.myapp.com:{anyPort}` should work.

**NOTE:**

Do not forget the add the URL in the google console too

Comment: Thank your for you answer, but how to catch google response? Because it is desktop app?

Comment: it should be as you are doing. You should not have to update any thing in the code

Comment: I can't image how to catch response, because response to https://api.myapp.com:{anyPort} will be send to my backend application such as Spring boot ??